# parallel operator in Spring Reactor and Netflix RxJava

Tags: project-reactor, rx-java2

The RxJava library used to have the parallel operator which was [discontinued](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1673) , however the current Spring Reactor project has a [parallel operator](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#parallel--)

What stops RxJava from being able to implement the parallel operator ?

I can see that there is project called [RxJavaParallel](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaParallel) which is trying to do this but I can't wrap my head around why it's being handled in this manner ? Is there is a inherent design limitation with the current RxJava implementations which make it much harder ?

**Update**

The kind of problem I was hoping to get solved

```
Flowable.range(1, 100)
.parallel(10)
.runOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(v -> httpClient.blockingGet("http://server/item/" + v))
.sequential()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(...);
```

This [PR](http://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4974) pointed by @akarnokd is exactly what I was looking for ! Wonder why it was not in there to begin with :)

**Update**

Thanks @akarnokd for the link and the reply, I guess it's this attitude that keeps the library simple for folks like myself. The [extensions project](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions) is worth looking at in case you cannot find a feature you are looking for in the main RxJava project

Comment: Your question is quite abstract. Perhaps you can specify what kind of tasks do you want to solve with such parallel operator.

Comment: http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.ru/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html - this might help.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4974

Comment: RxJava is a different community. Introducing new things, especially that increase the method count, has to happen gently; plus, I have the decency to try and verify my ideas outside of RxJava instead of dumping something onto the main project immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from 2.0.5, RxJava 2 now offers a similar `parallel()` API.